# Are wchar_t and multibyte functions part of ANSI C?

Tags: c, c89, wchar-t, ansi-c

`C99` and `C11` support `wchar_t` and multibyte functions .But I am not sure about `ANSI C` (1989).

Is it correct that `wchar_t` and multibyte functions (`mblen`, `mbstowcs`, `mbtowc`, `wcstombs`, `wctomb`) are part of ANSI C?

I don't find these functions in Kernighan and Ritchie book (C Programming Language (2nd Edition)).

[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-2nd-Brian-Kernighan/dp/0131103628](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628)

Comment: Maybe you have a 1st edition (1978) of the book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name `wchar_t` is in the C89 (and C99) standard(s), but it is not a langauge-supported type. It is a `typedef` for some integer type capable of holding the requisite number of bits. C89 7.1.6 [Standard Definitions ] says:

> wchar_t
>   which is an integral type whose range of values can
>   represent distinct codes for all members of the largest extended
>   character set specified among the supported locales; the null
>   character shall have the code value zero and each member of the basic
>   character set defined in 5.2.1 shall have a code value equal to its
>   value when used as the lone character in an integer character
>   constant.

This means that someone can define `wchar_t` to be whatever they want in C89 so long as `<stddef.h>` has not been `#include`d.

In C++, this is illegal; wchar_t is a keyword in that language.

---

As for the multibyte functions you referenced, they appear to be part of C89. Section 7.10.7 [Multibyte character functions] defines `mblen`, `mbtowc`, `wctomb`, and 7.10.8 [Multibyte string functions] defines `mbstowcs`, and `wcstombs` (all in `<stdlib.h>`). Note of course that because C89 does not have `const` that the `const`-qualified versions of these functions are not available.

Comment: "This means that someone can define `wchar_t` to be whatever they want in C89 so long as `<stddef.h>` has not been `#include`d. "

Technically yes, but then the behavior is undefined.  

C89, 4.1.2 says "All external identifiers declared in any of the [standard library] headers are reserved, whether or not the associated header is included. [...] If the program defines an external identifier with the same name as a reserved external identifier, even in a semantically equivalent form, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 2):

`wchar_t` is part of ANSI C (1989).

Comment: But why Ritchie missing multibyte functions in his book?

Comment: Not in my copy... care to cite a reference? It certainly is not listed in 6.1.1 [Keywords] on my copy..

Comment: if you go to page 272 of the books' index using the "Look Inside" feature of the amazon page you linked to, you will see `wchar_t`

Comment: They probably were deemed unimportant for inclusion in the book. `wchar_t` is included, though.

Answer (score 1):

`wchar_t` is perfectly C89 standard. In my edition, `wchar_t` is mentioned at section § A2.5.2 in Kernighan and Ritchie book.

Comment: I could not find multibyte functions.

Comment: There's a note in A2.5.2 that makes me believe this (`wchar_t`) was introduced in the 2nd edition of the book: "... the main intent in adding `wchar_t` was to accomodate Asian languages." *Note: the 1st edition was published in 1978.*

Comment: @pmg: If you believe it so much then find a standard reference to support it.

Comment: @BillyONeal: I'd like very much to have a 1st edition of the book. If I find one I'll try and remember to come here and update this question.

Comment: @pmg: The book doesn't matter; the standard does.